Retrieving data from an SSD MZ-JPV5120/0A6 removed from 2015 iMac
I have tried a few options, the main one being this device from Amazon.

https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/B07MVYYMVD

Whilst it all plugged in and the LED power lights lit up, it wasn't recognised by my new iMac as a drive. Seems this is very tricky to do and finding the right interface is not easy. Keen to see if anyone has had success in accessing this specific drive or can advise if I purchased the wrong adapter.

I’m assuming you still need advice on this - let’s keep the question simple. If you do things to resolve this, please use the answer section to report what you decided. (Rather than editing the question into a blog post of updates)
